# From Freshdesk, how to login to Jira app using oauth

Tags: jira, freshdesk

I log into Jira via Google Account, which I believe is oAuth.  Without a specific username and password, how do I use the Jira app inside Freshdesk?
I'd prefer a solution other than creating another email address, creating a new admin username/password in Jira, and then use this to access Jira through Freshdesk.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From your description, it seems you are owning a JIRA account created using your Google credentials.

So, when setting up JIRA inside Freshdesk, click install you will be redirected to the page where you need to enter JIRA credentials. There, just click google sign in and sign in using the same google account.

This should help you to log in without having to create new account!